# Python3 set nonexistent attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Was doing something this morning and thought this was weird. Why am I able to do this? I would think this should bounce back saying there is no rank attribute.

```
class EmployeeClass(object):
    __status = None

def __init__(self, status):
    self.__status = status

def get_status(self):
    return self.__status

def set_status(self, status):
    self.__status = status


John_Smith = EmployeeClass("Employed")
John_Smith.rank = 'Director'
print(John_Smith.rank)
```

This actually runs and returns "Director" to me. I don't quite understand that, this line should fail shouldn't it?

```
John_Smith.rank = 'Director'
```